# Task definition and its instances

Tags: ambiguity

I have a system which allows to set tasks for users. Each task has to be completed everyday and has a recurring due time.

To keep the history of completions/failures, there is another entity: a task assignment for some specific date.

To give an example, you have the "brush your teeth" task set to 10:00 every day. An "instance" of this task template is set every day.

Which good, short, self-explanatory terms can be used to name these two types? "Task" and "Assignment"? "Task definition" and "Task"? I can't think of a good matching name for that :)

Comment: You might like to check out [this earlier question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/) regarding your *system which allows to [do something]*. As for your specific question, is there some real-world context (as opposed to Off Topic naming of elements within software) where you need to present both of these terms? The *exact* context would be helpful.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Do you know where is the best place for choice of words/terms for software? I think this Q probably does belong there -- a useful place for many SW developers.

Comment: @martin: The names of variables, functions, classes, and such would be to a considerable extent application-specific. I find it hard to imagine *any* site would offer much help for something like that. Who would run it, and why? Every answer would tend to be unique, and largely worthless to anyone else even if it satisfied the original asker. But [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions) here might be able to help with more general aspects of *naming conventions*.

Comment: I just answered but now i'm not sure what you're asking: please edit the question to indicate if you're asking about recurring vs one-time tasks, or about types vs instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need two phrases, rather than words, for the two types of tasks:

1. recurring/repeating task

   one-time/individual/*ad hoc* task