# "allow insertion" or "allow inserting" or "allow to insert"

Tags: grammar

I have some doubts about using `ing`-verb in the following case:

> Such data structures don't allow insretion/inserting/to insert any
>   kind of objects.

Is it considered grammatically correct to say that in all three ways? I'm not sure about `ing`-verb because I didn't find that we can use it in that way. For instance, [there](http://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/pt-br/english-grammar/verbs/verbs-followed-ing-clauses).

Comment: Who is doing the inserting and why aren't they referred to in the sentence? The nominal _insertion_ is the only grammatical choice, without a subject for a verbal clause. If _insertion_ is used, the whole phrase should be _allow the insertion of_. But it's still not clear who or what is forbidding whom or what to insert what where. If your readers are already clear on all that, no problem.

Comment: @tchrist BTW, _allow_ is not in the list of the verbs that is being used with a gerund. Why is it possible to use along with the gerund?

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'm sorry, I can't find an answer in the link you provided. Why do you think the question is related?

Comment: @St.Antario: The [accepted answer in my closevote](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/85080/2637) makes it clear that *it allows to insert something* is unacceptable to native speakers (probably a "Germanism"). The specific action being [dis]allowed isn't syntactically significant - the OP himself there endorses *it allows the insertion of X* (as does John Lawler here) or *it allows one to insert X*. Besides which I consider this question better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I got that, TY. Are there another verbs that require to have a pronoun after their?

Comment: @St.Antario: I don't understand your question. I happened to use "it" to save space in a comment, but I don't see how that's relevant to anything being discussed here. But to repeat - you should probably be asking about such matters on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You said that _it allows to insert something_ is incorrect, but _it allows us to insert something_ is acceptable. So it's reasonable to ask if there are another verbs like _allow_, which requires to put a pronoun after it, I mean the following pattern ___verb__ one to do X_, like in your example. And it directly relates to the question here. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: @St.Antario: As I said, I think questions like that belong on ELL. There's the pattern *I want [**him**] to leave*, where if the subject for the verbal clause (**him** in that example) isn't specified then by implication it's the same as the subject of the main verb *(I want **me/myself** to leave)*. The key issue, as initially made by John, is *Who is doing the wanting/inserting and why aren't they referred to in the sentence?* I don't know, because it's not the kind of stuff they teach native speakers in school, but I'd guess it *must* be explicitly specified if it's not the main subject.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Such data structures don't allow the insertion of any kind of objects.
>
> Such data structures don't allow us to insert any kind of objects.
>
> Such data structures don't allow inserting any kind of objects.

Comment: I'd add "inserting"; it looks perfectly good to me.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain why you added the _us_ pronoun between allow and the infinitive? Why kind of grammar does it relate to?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if gerund is being alluded here.  'Inserting' is not necessarily a verb!  There need not be any doubts any 'ing-verb', which is quite common in gerund.

Comment: @Raghuraman This post contains two comments and no answers. I am recommending deletion.

Comment: Please support your answer with sources. That makes your answer stronger, and more likely to be viewed as correct. Otherwise, even if it's correct, it's likely to be viewed as only opinion. The [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will give you guidance on how to use this site.